# How to list network shared items in terminal

Tags: macos, terminal.app

Is there a way to list the network shared items in the Terminal command line the way Finder sees them in the Mac OS X GUI?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In terminal, use `ls` to get a directory listing.

The mounted volumes are under `/Volumes` so you want to use

`ls /Volumes` to see the attached network drives.

**EDIT based on OPs comment**

ahh, so you want to see a listing of the servers available (or more accurately, the servers which are registered for discovery). I believe the 'Networks' tab reflects Bonjour discovery services.

So, based on this [Hint about Bonjour](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20051026183044858) and [This StackOverflow Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379413/can-i-use-bonjour-from-command-line)
you are probably looking for `dns-sd` but you would need to identify which services (`ssh`, `afp`, `lpr` etc) you are expecting to find.

try: `dns-sd -B _ssh._tcp .` or `dns-sd -B _afpovertcp._tcp .`

Please note, the man page for `dns-sd` states:

> The dns-sd command is primarily intended for interactive use.  Because its command-line arguments and output format are subject to change, invoking it from a shell script will generally be fragile.

Comment: How do I see all the (unattached) Network computers like I do when I press apple-shift-k in the Finder?

Comment: Not all attached network drives are under /Volumes. Using the mount command you can put them other places.

Comment: Sorry for reviving a stale answer, but regarding @JohnHenckel's comment, you can use df -h to list other mounts.